# Ajax Infinite Loop

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

I have some AJAX code I would like to keep going every 1 second. I added this into my HTML page to see if it would keep updating on it's own, but I have to refresh to see the change.

```
        while (1) {
            getTime();
        }
```

This didn't work on to keep updating, it never updated my text. What is a way of having Ajax do something over and over?

Here is getTime():

```
        function getTime() {
            if (str=="") {
                document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML="";
                return;
            } 

            if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
                xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
            } else {// code for IE6, IE5
                xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            }

            xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
                if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {
                    document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
                }
            }

            xmlhttp.open("GET","auction.php?getTime=1",true);
            xmlhttp.send();

            setTimeout(getTime, 1000);
        }
```

Thanks!

Comment: Can you provide the source for `getTime`?

Answer (score 1):

Repetitive tasks are usually done in javascript using [`setInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.setInterval):

> `window.setInterval`
>   Calls a function or executes a code snippet repeatedly, with a fixed time delay between each call to that function.

In your example, that would be

```
setInterval(getTime, 1000);
```

Comment: It isn't updating by itself I still need to refresh.

Answer (score 0):

[`setInterval()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.setInterval) may be your best bet - alternatively, `setTimeout` repeatedly resetting itself on AJAX success.

Answer (score 0):

```
setInterval(getTime, 1000); // Run getTime() every second
setInterval(getTime, 200);  // Run getTime() every 200 milliseconds
```

Comment: It isn't updating by itself I still need to refresh.

Answer (score 0):

You code is a infinite loop, and will get into the limit number of open connections from js a browser can handle very soon.

Use `window.setInterval` to do such thing.

```
window.setInterval(getTime, 1000);
```

Comment: It isn't updating by itself I still need to refresh.

Comment: @Alec Yes, shouldn't do the refresh work in your ajax callback function?

Comment: I'm new to AJAX, so could you explain what you're saying?

Comment: @Alec Your function already did `setTimeout(getTime, 1000);`, so just remove the while loop, `getTime();` only will be ok.

Answer (score 0):

```
function getTime(){
     setTimeout(getTime, [interval]);
}
```

This should do it.

Comment: Shouldn't it be window.setTimeout()?

Comment: It works even without `window` [Samples](http://www.electrictoolbox.com/using-settimeout-javascript/)

Comment: I just added my getTime() method. I put this in, and it didn't do it by itself.

Comment: Can you comment out `if (str=="") {
                document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML="";
                return;
            }`? Just to test. Then try again.

Comment: I just did that, but it shows the text for a second or less then all the text disappears.

Comment: Then it might mean that `auction.php` returns no `String` value.

Comment: Then what do I do about that?

Comment: Edit your `auction.php`? Or if you're lost post another question regarding that file.